# issue in installing npm package in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, npm, package

I am new here installing laravel *"npm package"* with **npm install** command but it throws this error:

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

My command:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project>npm install
```

Comment: Is `npm` installed?

Comment: npm is not installed or not added to PATH

Answer (score 1):

Just Download and Install Node.js from here https://nodejs.org/en/

If you run the downloaded file and install it, they will automatically configure for your system

You don't need any other configurations anymore, now you can use the **npm** command anywhere

---

Still ERROR?

Follow the steps:

1. Go to **My Computer** Properties
2. Click **Advanced System Setting**
3. Click **Advanced**
4. Then, Click **Environment Variable** button
5. Now you have Environment variable window: From *System Variable*, Select **Path**
6. Click **Edit**
7. At the end of the Variable value, add `;C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

---

Now you can use the **npm** command anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) and then you can use `npm`.